# Find the angle from given information

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

In this, how are $\measuredangle PAD$ and $\measuredangle DBA$ equal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are equal by alternate segment theorem:

"The alternate segment theorem states that in any circle, the angle between a chord and a tangent through one of the end points of the chord is equal to the angle in the alternate segment."

[image]

In this picture, the angles which are the same colour are equal. Applying this to your diagram, we can see that $\measuredangle PAD = \measuredangle DBA$

Do you require a proof?

Edit (proof):

[image]